# Acessing MPI_WTIME in single precision

Tags: time, fortran

I need to get wall time in single precision. MPI_WTIME however returns the value in double precision. To work around this I try:

```
subroutine wtime

real(kind=8)   :: t_now
real           :: wt

t_now = MPI_WTIME()

if ( t_now > 1e38 ) then
    wt = 1e30
else if ( t_now < 1e-38 ) then
    wt = 0
end if

end subroutine wtime
```

Is there a fortran equivalent of `MPI_WTIME()` that I can use instead to get wall time in single precision?

I compile my code with the flag `-real-size 32` so by default `real` is of kind 4.

Comment: Have a look at the intrinsic `cpu_time`.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using `cpu_time` but this has the limitation that : _"The time measured only accounts for the amount of time that the program is actually running, and not the time that a program is suspended or waiting"_ I need to know the elapsed wall time

Comment: Then you might get what you want by wrapping either `system_clock` or `date_and_time` into a function returning a 4-byte real.